# CORS: login.windows.net origin is null

Tags: cors, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, windows-authentication

I'm setting up Azure Active Directory authentication for Azure Functions. 
Chrome gives me this error:
`Failed to load https://login.windows.net/fa7adf0d... &state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252FAuditGetAll' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

[image: Here's Network tab]
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)?

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> CORS: login.windows.net origin is null

In your case, it seems that you need to config azure function CORS.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) allows JavaScript code running in a browser on an external host to interact with your backend. Specify the origins that should be allowed to make cross-origin calls (for example: http://example.com:12345). To allow all, **use "*"** and remove all other origins from the list. Slashes are not allowed as part of domain or after TLD. [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#app-service-cors-vs-your-cors)

[image]

Comment: This doesn't help me with my problem. I have CORS set up in my function code like here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/12/azure-functions-access-control-allow-credentials-with-cors/ . But I can't set up CORS on redirect to windows authentication. I am not making that call, AAD does it. As far as I understand.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issiue? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this error you need to get accessToken (on javascript side) and send it together with other headers when call AAD secured Azure function:

```
httpClient.get(apiUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, 
    {
        headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?